# Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1

Tags: exception, managed-c++

HI,
I have desinged a console application to test my C++ project(.Net framework 3.5). I created a setup for this application and installed it on a virtual machine so as to test it.
But whenever I run this installed app on VM, it gives me unhandled exception, saying, "Could not load XYZ assembly or one of its dependencies. This application is failed to start because application configuration is incorrect. Reinstalling the application may fix the proble(Exception from HRESULT: 0x800736B1)"

How can I fix this?

Thanks,
Kapil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have same problem but it get resolved when I change my setting to "Release" in visual studio.

i.e build your assembly in "Release" mode.

Comment: can someone explain the logic for this behavior? how come "Debug" dll load fails and "Release" works??

Comment: @eyal I think it's to do with the debug C runtime not being present on the target machine.

Comment: @eyal old question but I tried to explain this at the bottom. probably misconfiguration on the config file

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but since it was the first result in google I'll add this for the next person.

The problem is a missing C++ redistributable, as mastro said. For me, I needed the 2008 version. I googled "visual studio c++ redistributable 2008" and the first result was a Microsoft support page with exactly what I needed.

If you know which version your DLL was developed with just install that one, but if you're like me and you have no clue, just install different years one at a time until it works. I got lucky with 2008 on my first try.

Comment: Just a note, I had the same problem and installing vcredist 2008 didn't work at first. Instead, I needed a **specific** version of vcredist_2008 (I had 3 different ones installed in my main machine).

Answer (score 2):

The problem is what anthony said.

It is not finding the debug C+ runtime in the virtual machine. They are not distributable. You have to install Visual studio or a subset of it.

You can see this: [How to install VC80CRT debug runtimes without full visual studio 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2804589/how-to-install-vc80crt-debug-runtimes-without-full-visual-studio-2005)

Answer (score 0):

In my case the error was provoked due to a misconfiguration in the **.config** file (a parser error in the xml .config file with two !!). I think that the solution of this question works because changing to **Release Mode** provokes using a different config file.

I found the solution thanks to this [page](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cesardelatorre/the-application-has-failed-to-start-because-its-side-by-side-configuration-is-incorrect-error-related-to-mmc-exe-programs-and-weird-cause-simple-solution/) and we have something similar here in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3961742/the-application-has-failed-to-start-because-its-side-by-side-configuration-is-in/39701014#39701014).