# Side-by-side configuration error in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, side-by-side

I installed Visual Studio 2019 but when I open it this error occurs:

> "The application has failed to start because its side-by-side
> configuration is incorrect. Please see the application event log or
> use the command-line sxstrace.exe for more details."

When I try to repair the visual studio this error occurs:

```
"Error-2146233033: Package is corrupted

Couldn't repair Microsoft.NetCore.TargetingPack.3.1.3.1.0"
```

Comment: This is just a wild guess, but did you install older version(s) of Visual Studio after installing VS 2019?  It's safest to start with installing the oldest version you need first, then add newer versions in order, that is 2015 then 2017 then 2019 NOT 2019 then 2015.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue and I tried the following.

- Repair the Microsoft C++ redistributable versions on your machine.
  Versions from 2013 onwards have this option by right clicking on it.
  For version 2010 and older download the respective version from the MS website.
  (This did not fix the issue for me)
- Uninstall C++ installations and re-installed them.
- Uninstall VS2019 and re-install it.

For me the above approach worked, but I cannot be certain which part fixed the issue.

Comment: Maybe use the sxstrace command line:  Example sxstrace trace -logfile:c:\users\myprofilename\desktop\sxstrace.etl - now if I can figure how to open an etl file.   OK, use event log - etl file has no names but shows an eventid 261